# Load profile avatars in chat using protocol relative URLs

Tags: bug, chat, profile-picture, ssl

I get a Mixed Content warning for all chat rooms due to users' profile pictures being loaded exclusively over http.

Can we change the profile pictures to be loaded with a protocol relative URL?

[image: Console screenshot]

Comment: SE does not support https yet, so better use the http version, this includes chat. If using https, well, we can expect things to break.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm aware, but it's still a trivial fix on something that's very nearly complete anyway.

Comment: Well, judging from the long years it's taking them, I'm sure it's not trivial. Dunno why, only a dev can tell.